# How to stay logged in on whatsdesk on ubuntu

Tags: login, whatsapp

I don't use a smartphone, never used one and will never do.

I was looking for a way to use whatsapp without a smartphone, and found whatsdesk on ubuntu, which at first sight seemed to work well: I have an old smartphone that my wife doesn't use anymore, I install whatsapp there linking it to my phone number, use the QR code to link the account to my whatsdesk installation, and then uninstall the app from the smartphone.

The problem is that, after approximately 24 hours, whatsdesk logs me out automatically and I have to redo everything again. Is it possible to configure whatsdesk to stay logged in for longer? It would be fine if it logged me out, let's say, once a month or similar.

I used to use Franz in the past, which did keep me logged in for months without ever bothering me, but Franz had other issues and caused crashes on ubuntu. Whatsdesk seems to work much better, so if there is a way to stay logged in it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

consider using `WhatsApp.web in your browser. I use this with Firefox and it remains persistently active. You'll need to use a smartphone at first to log in to your account capturing the QR code image to verify yourself for security reasons.

https://web.whatsapp.com/

I have it set as a pinned tab in Firefox and  it restores as such when FF is closed and re-opened.